# jQuery function to hide elements based on HTML5 data tags not running on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on a small function in jQuery to hide elements based on values in their data tags. For example, if the value of bathrooms is 3 hide all elements that do less than 3 bathrooms set in the tag.

The hiding function has worked before but when I set it up like this it doesn't seem to go. Any ideas?

```
function search(){
    $baths = $('#baths').val();
    $beds = $('#bedrooms').val();
    $style = $('#modelstyle').val();

    $("models").show();

    $("[data-baths]").filter(function(){
        return parseInt($(this).attr('data-baths'), 10) < $baths;
    }).hide();


    $("[data-beds]").filter(function(){
        return parseInt($(this).attr('data-beds'), 10) < $beds;
    }).hide();


    $("[data-style]").filter(function(){
        return parseInt($(this).attr('data-style'), 10) != $style;
    }).hide();
};

$('#search').click(search());
```

Comment: You need to put a `var` before the `$baths`, `$beds`,and `$style` variables at the top of your search function. Currently you are leaking these variables globally. (Just a hint, not an answer)

Comment: @BlakeSimpson Thanks for the tip, I do not want these global so I went ahead and changed their scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give the reference to the `search()` function to the handler, not the *result* of the function. Remove the brackets after the `search` call:

```
$('#search').click(search);
```